# Unexpected empty result using spring query method

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I am building an application with a REST API using spring boot and JPA connected to a MySQL database. To search for names in the User class I have implemented a query method: `List< User > findByFirstnameLike( String name );`

This method only returns a result on an exact match, which is not what I wanted. Have I misunderstood something about its use?

The repository interface:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    public List< User > findByFirstname( String name );

    public List< User > findByFirstnameLike( String name );
}
```

The service bean method:

```
@Override
public List<User> findByFirstNameLike(String name) {
    logger.info( "searching for first name: {}", name);
    List< User > ret = userRepo.findByFirstnameLike(name);

    if( null == ret ){
        logger.info("No list returned from search");
    }
    else{
        logger.info( "List size = {}", ret.size() );
    }

    return( ret );
}
```

The REST interface method:

```
@RequestMapping(
        value="/{firstName}",
        method=RequestMethod.GET,
        produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE )
public ResponseEntity< List< User > > SearchForUserByFirstName( @PathVariable( "firstName" ) String firstName ){
    return( new ResponseEntity< List< User > >( userService.findByFirstNameLike( firstName ), HttpStatus.OK) );
}
```

Entity class:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    public enum Department {
        BS, BA, BT, BD, UX, SALES
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String firstname;

    private String lastname;

    private String email;

    private String phone;

    private Department department;
```

So... having a user in the database with the name "Adam", the query method returns an empty list for any string except for "Adam".

Edit 2:
After turning on show SQL and inserting an object to the database, I search for a part of the first name and yield this output and an empty List:

```
searching for first name: dam <-- This is the log print
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_6_, user0_.department as 
departme2_6_, user0_.email as email3_6_, user0_.firstname as 
firstnam4_6_, user0_.lastname as lastname5_6_, user0_.phone as 
phone6_6_ from user user0_ where user0_.firstname like ?
```

The searhing for an exact match which returns an array with one object:

```
searching for first name: Adam
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_6_, user0_.department as 
departme2_6_, user0_.email as email3_6_, user0_.firstname as 
firstnam4_6_, user0_.lastname as lastname5_6_, user0_.phone as 
phone6_6_ from user user0_ where user0_.firstname like ?
```

Comment: Is there a misspelling, `firstname` vs `firstName`?

Comment: Can you turn on show sql and execute it against your db?

Comment: Added the entity class. Don't think there is a spelling issue.

Comment: @blur0224: I added the SQL output.

Comment: Typically you would use like '%dam' if you wanted to return Adam.  Or 'Ada%'.  Does the documentation specify that you have to put the %% wild cards in when using the like?

Comment: I havent seen that anywhere in the docs, but that did the difference. I would have expected that to be done implicitly. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `findByFirstnameContaining` instead of `findByFirstnameLike`.

I am not sure how `like` is interpreted. But the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html) says:

```
Keyword     | Sample                    | JPQL snippet

Containing  | findByFirstnameContaining | … where x.firstname like ?1 (parameter bound wrapped in %)
```

And I suppose you want to search for `%dam%`.

If you want to bound the wildcard at the beginning or ending this is also possible: `findByFirstnameStartingWith` or `findByFirstnameEndingWith`.

Comment: Now I see! I am an idiot ;) I have read it many times, but not noticed that! Sorry for wasting your time :/

Comment: @PeterLundgren No problem. Was a pleasure to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html):

> **Keyword | Sample | JPQL snippet**
>   Like | findByFirstnameLike… | where x.firstname like ?1

The value passed as an argument must include '%', for example:

**List ret = userRepo.findByFirstnameLike(name+"%");**

Answer (score 0):

By default, Boot automatically creates table structures from any classes annotated with @Entity. It’s simple to override this behavior with the following property settings, shown here from the app’s application.properties file:

spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

Comment: Answer doesn't satisfy the actual question.